migrating jenkins from older version to newer version and doing it on another server
For some  reasons we have to move Jenkins from 2.176.2 which is running in centos 7 to new jenkins version 2.440.3 on debian12 different server. As we are on a old version so a updated is also need on same time. What are things we should consider. Also not sure if we need to configure all jobs in new instance manually or there is faster way to clone them from existing instance. We have around 5 jobs
and we have script to deploy the old plugins from old server
solution and things need to be consider before migrating

No, you don't have to manually create all the jobs or plugins in the new Jenkins instance, you can simply copy the Jenkins home from your old server to your new one. This will automatically move all the jobs and their build histories, plugins, views, slave configurations, credentials, etc... You can refer to the doc for more info, as well as this answer for a summarized explanation.
As for things to consider, you are moving up a version, so ensure that your plugins are all compatible and there are no breaking changes related to your jobs. You are also moving from RHEL based to Debian based, so check your jobs to make sure there are no flavor-specific bash scripts that will break.
